# Get post content with ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress, post

I have a code using ajax request loads titles of post. 
It works like this:
- Choose from the list of months and categories
- The event "change" uploading list

I'm doing with this instruction http://wp-kama.ru/id_652/dinamicheskiy-arhiv-bloga-s-ispolzovaniem-jquery-ajax.html

It show title post and time.
I want to show content post.
I try get_post($id);, but not work.

```
$id = 11914;// Обязательно передавать переменную
$post = get_post($id); 
$content = $post->post_content;
if (have_posts()) { 
    echo "<tr><td>$content</td></tr>";
}
```

Please, ask me, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Show ur ajax call pls.

Comment: So, i finally get it - change ur tags for PHP, Wordpress, seems that  ur trouble not in ajax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Syntax of ajax is

```
$.post( "test.php", { name: "John", time: "2pm" })
  .done(function( data ) {
    alert( "Data Loaded: " + data );
});
```

where `test.php` - your url, and then `{ name: "John", time: "2pm" }` - params for send, and in callback - u have returned result ( `data` is a result from server ).

In php post params are in $_POST['%%% key_of_parameter %%%']

For example, in code above, in `$_POST['name'] == "John";`

(If I understand your question right)

P.S. Тут не особо расположены к гайдам на русском, бро)

Comment: Thanks for you answer
But I return HTML content, which is formed in test.php.
I'm write $content in returned html code (in my case in the TABLE )

Answer (score 0):

Thanks
I found a solution
In test.php Im write :

```
$post_id = 8994;
$queried_post = get_post($post_id);
$content = $queried_post->post_content;
$content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);
$content = str_replace(']]>', ']]&gt;', $content);
echo $content;
```

and my ajax request return content of a post number 8964